# Creating a multidimensional array / list from a function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a function `f([i_0, i_1, ..., i_k-1])` which takes as input a `k`-dimensional array of integers and returns some object.

Given the range for each index (as a two-dimensional array `ranges=[i_0_range, i_1_range, ...]`), how do I generate a `k`-dimensional list / array containing objects evaluated for each value of indices?

If `k` was fixed, I'd simply do `k` nested loops. But I would like to have a solution working for any `k`. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? What did you expect? You say you have a function, please share the code.

Comment: I have no idea what to try :( I was thinking about some sort of recursive / dynamic solution. Note that the particular form of the function is not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all the different combinations of indexes from the ranges. You can then iterate over the tuples produced by that iterator, calling `f` for each tuple. For example, if `f` is defined to return a string of the input indexes:

```
import itertools

def f(indexes):
    return ','.join(map(str, indexes))
    
ranges = [range(0, 2), range(1, 3), range(2, 4)]

objs = [f(list(t)) for t in itertools.product(*ranges)]
print(objs)
```

Output:

```
['0,1,2', '0,1,3', '0,2,2', '0,2,3', '1,1,2', '1,1,3', '1,2,2', '1,2,3']
```

Note that dependent on your implementation of `f`, it might not be necessary to convert the returned tuple from `itertools.product` to a list and you could just use `f(t)` instead of `f(list(t))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Seems to do the job. Could you please elaborate what `itertools.product(*ranges)` does, and why you called `f` with `[*t]` argument? (Sorry, apparently I'm not familiar with these Python basics.)

Comment: `*ranges` flattens the `ranges` array, so that each element is passed separately to `itertools.product`, which then creates the cartesian product of each of the ranges. Note that I changed the code to be `f(list(t)) for t in itertools.product(*ranges)` so that it would correctly deal with `k` greater than 2; `itertools.product` returns a tuple of values (for `i_0, i_1, ..., i_k`), `list(t)` then converts that into a list as described in your question. Dependent on your implementation of `f`, it might not be necessary to convert to a list and you could just use `f(t)`